# How to deal with assigning variables as value?

Tags: bash, shell-script

How to deal with assigning variables as below?
I am assigning value `var1=1` next assigning `var2=$var1`, but every time I change value of `var1`, `echo $var2` shows always old value i.e

```
# var1=1
# var2=$var1
# echo $var2
1
```

```
# var1=2
# echo $var2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common miss-conception about how **many**/**most** programming languages work.

In imperative languages (`bash`/`C`/`Java`/`python`....), the `=` operator does **not** work the same way as in maths.

`a=1` means put 1 into `a` (overwriting what was there).

I.E.

```
var1=1       # var1 ← 1      #overwrite var1 with 1 
var2=$var1   # var2 ← $var1  #overwrite var2 with evaluation of $var1 (i.e 1) 
var1=2       # var1 ← 2      #overwrite var1 with 2
stdout ←← $var2              #append $var2 to stdout
```

Therefore

```
#              var1   var2
var1=1       #  1      n/a     
var2=$var1   #  1      1
var1=2       #  2      1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the value of `var1` to `var2` you have two independent variables `var1` and `var2` which just happen to have the same values.

You could use a variable `var2` declared with the `nameref` attribute for a reference to `var1`.

```
$ var1=1
$ declare -n var2=var1
$ echo "$var2"
1
$ var1=2
$ echo "$var2"
2
$ var2=3
$ echo "$var2 $var1"
3 3
```